# Почему передается неправильное значение в bgcolol?

Tags: php

Записываю значение в переменную, проверяю значение, показывает blue, использую эту переменную в атрибутах таблицы, получаю неверное значение

```
Цвет фона таблицы <select name="bgcol" tabindex="4">
     <option  value="white" >Белый</option>
     <option  value="blue" selected>Синий</option>
     <option  value="yellow">Жёлтый</option>
     <option  value="green">Зелёный</option>
</select><br>
```

Затем обращаюсь

```
$color = $_POST['bgcol'];
echo'<table border="5" bgcolor = "$color"';
```

Цвет фона получается черный, если убираю кавычки становится красным, а должен вообще быть синий

Comment: в одинарных кавычках подстановка переменных не осуществляется

Comment: @Gedweb использую в двойных кавычках "$color", таблица становится черного цвета, хотя в переменной $color хранится другое значение

Comment: сама строка в ординарных же
`echo "<table border='5' bgcolor = '$color'";`

Comment: @Gedweb спасибо)